# Apache is not serving continuesly after restarting through browser using php

Tags: php, apache, http, sh, phpseclib

I have a `php` script as given below.

```
<?php

    $v = '10.3.2.0';
    $t = '6969';

    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($v,$t);
    if (!$ssh->login('myuser','abcdef')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }else{
            $ssh->exec('sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload');
            echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Here my problem is, when I execute this script through web browser, after executing the bash command I have given inside `$ssh->exec()` (which will reload the apache browser and the command executing fine here), it is not echoing anything (In my case I need to get "ok" as response).When I anaylyse through firebug my result is something like this.

[image]

I know this is only the problem when reloading apache. Other commands also working fine instead reloading apache. Please help me to figure out this problem since I need to restart my apache server and continuing serving after restart. Please advice as I am a very beginner in PHP.Thanks a in advance.

Comment: I am facing this problem too, I tried adding these commands:
$ssh->read('Reloading web server config: apache2.');     $ssh->read();
after the exec but no luck.

Comment: I don't know why ya'll would expect this to work. It's like asking why a movie is no longer playing after you rebooted your computer. It's because you rebooted your computer ;) In the case of PHP / Apache each call to PHP made via a webbrowser is an Apache process so when you restart Apache those processes go away. The script would work fine if you did it via the CLI or a cronjob. If you want a better explanation maybe try posting in superuser.com or something.